# What is this error raised by multiprocessing of scikit-learn model training?

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, scikit-learn, joblib

When I train my models with multiprocessing support its occurs to have such error after a while;

```
Failed to save <type 'numpy.ndarray'> to .npy file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 271, in save
    obj, filename = self._write_array(obj, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 231, in _write_array
    self.np.save(filename, array)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 491, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 584, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
IOError: 495340 requested and 502 written
```

I seems there is a IOError due to space devotion but when I check with `df -h` every drive has enough space.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: also seeing this. any solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: I am not sure but seems like /tmp is out of space

Comment: Indeed, in my case it was the docker /dev/shm temp, as covered by https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/168